# Searching for ^ character in a MySQL table

Tags: mysql

```
select Column1 from Table where Column1 regexp '^';
```

Obviously, that doesn't work, but how do I literally search for all instances where the values in Column1 contains the character "^"(carot)?

Comment: `select Column from Table where Column like '%^%'`? `regexp` is a bit overkill.

Comment: Is this asking for finding `^` in a column's *name* or in a column's *value*?

Comment: The columns value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a regular expression but escape the `^` metacharacter:

```
WHERE `column` REGEXP '\^'
```

Or you can use the `LIKE` predicate, which does not treat `^` as a metacharacter:

```
WHERE `column` LIKE '%^%'
```

@tadman asks in a comment if you're searching for data values in a column, or the column names themselves, that contain `^`? I had the same thought when I first ready your question.

If you want to search for a character in the *names* of tables or columns, then use the INFORMATION_SCHEMA, for example:

```
SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%^%';
```